# Inconsistent usage of Geany colour schemes

Tags: colors, geany

I'm new to developing C/C++ projects on Linux (specifically **Raspberry Pi**).  I find that ***Geany*** seems to do everything I need.  I also installed the official *Colour Schemes* as specified on the GitHub page.  Starting Geany from the *Start/Programming* menu, I changed to the theme I like.  Any time I re-start from the menu, I get my selected colour scheme as expected.

However, if I double click on a file (say **.cpp, *.h* or even the project file **.geany*) I get the generic, Default colour scheme.  If I go to *Change Colour Scheme...* it only shows the two default themes (*Default* and *Alternate*).

It appears to have a different ***.config/geany/colorschemes*** location depending on how I start Geany.  Is this a bug or a feature (that I'm not understanding)?  ... or is there a way in Geany or Linux for me to get a consistent experience?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My fault.  Somewhere along the way, I set up the File Manager menu item to start with sudo.  It was accessing files as root and thus was looking in root's .config.